# Unexplainable margin @ top of page

Tags: css, wordpress, margin

I have a strange margin at the top of the page on this site. Strange thing is that it does not always appear but most of the times it does. So I guess it is not an actual margin or padding but can it be caused by something else?

https://www.nederweert24.nl/ontdek-nederweert/

It appears like this:

[image]

But it should be like this:

[image]

PS: it is not caused bij the Wordpress adminbar, cause when logged out the problem persists.

Comment: First of all: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it Secondly: Can’t reproduce; do you mean it only occurs on specific sub-pages, or does it show sometimes and sometimes not on the same page? _Collapsing margins_ would be the usual suspect if it was on specific pages with a specific HTML structure that is different from the rest (like a headline element with margin-top as first child.)

Comment: I’d start by fixing at least the more serious errors though, https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nederweert24.nl%2Fontdek-nederweert%2F

Comment: I am unable to repro this error, possibly causing by WP Admin bar, really. See this: [**Preview**](https://i.imgur.com/In0u1LE.png)

Comment: Click the link, get hit by a cookie bar, a push notification message and ads. Aaaand I'm out.

Comment: The relevant code should be in the question. We are not here to dig trough your code. If the site changes the question wouldn't maken sense

Comment: Thank you, I will keep this in mind for the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not the wp admin bar. I went on page and just explored. When i clicked the logo i saw the problem you stated and inspected it to see whats causing it.
I started looking in whats above the header and started deleting some stuff until i stumbled upon something that fixed the "margin".

[image]

Just click on the pic and you'll see it. I deleted this image I marked red. Then the header jumped back to normal. There is a lot above your header that i think is unnecessary and thereby taking up that space randomly. I hope you can find out where that image comes from because I cant really go into your wordpress :p

Comment: The relevant code should be in the question. There is no need to dig trough the linked website

Comment: @SuperDJ I can understand its a bit hard to put code here from wordpress so just give him a break. I only tried to just help him out with his problem and :) If you dont agree there are many other questions to look at!

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with your `header` margin. You just want to update in your css follow below.

1. Reduce the `.site-header` margin to move-up the logo.

> .site-header {margin-top: 15px;}

2. Add `z-index` and `top` spacing for your `.thrid-nav-menu`.

> .geodir-page .third-nav-menu {
>         position: absolute;
>         display: block;
>         float: right;
>         text-align: right;
>         z-index: 999;
>         top: 20px;
>       }